# SSD Resnet 50 FPN Loss function clarification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, loss-function, object-detection-api

I am using tensorflow object detection api on my dataset. I am using ssd-resnet50-fpn model. While training, I see that classification loss and localization loss has converged but the total loss is still decreasing. Also total loss is not coming out to be the sum of classification loss and localization los. Any ideas on why this is happening. I am using train.py in object_detection/legacy/ folder to train on my dataset. Attached image for the same.

[image: Loss graphs]

Answer (score 0):

Total loss is the sum of classification loss, localization loss and L2 loss applied to trainable variables, and weightened by "weight_decay"